# PiFace InputListener (Switch) to turn on LEDs in Python

Tags: python, switch-statement, raspberry-pi, led, debian-based

I am studying how to work with the Rasberry Pi and the PiFace right now. Code is written in Python.

My problem is:
I can't seem to get anything executed once I press one of the 4 switches on the PiFace. I managed to make a program that plays with the lights.

The documentation we got from our prof is here: 
https://piface.github.io/pifacedigitalio/example.html

I want to have an Interrupt with a listener triggering the corresponding LED. Switch 1 pressed -> LED 1 triggers.

Here's my code so far (doesn't work).

```
import pifacedigitalio

def toggle_led0(event):
    event.chip.leds[0].toggle()

def toggle_led1(event):
    event.chip.leds[1].toggle()

def toggle_led2(event):
    event.chip.leds[2].toggle()

def toggle_led3(event):
    event.chip.leds[3].toggle()

pifacedigital = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital()
listener = pifacedigitalio.SwitchEventListener(chip=pifacedigital)
listener.register(0, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_FALLING_EDGE, toggle_led0)
listener.register(1, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_FALLING_EDGE, toggle_led1)
listener.register(2, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_FALLING_EDGE, toggle_led2)
listener.register(3, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_FALLING_EDGE, toggle_led3)
listener.activate()
```

Comment: What is `pifacedigitalio.SwitchEventListener`?...Shouldn't be `pifacedigitalio.core.InputEventListener` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works on my Pi B

```
import pifacedigitalio
from time import sleep
def lighton(event):
    try:
        print("on pressed")
        event.chip.relays[0].value = 1
    except:
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
def lightoff(event):
    try:
        print("off pressed")
        event.chip.relays[0].value = 0
    except:
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
pfd = pifacedigitalio.PiFaceDigital()
listener = pifacedigitalio.InputEventListener(chip=pfd)
listener.register(0, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_FALLING_EDGE, lighton)
print("Registered listener0")
listener.register(1, pifacedigitalio.IODIR_FALLING_EDGE, lightoff)
print("Registered listener1")
try:
    listener.activate()
    print("Activated all")
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    print("\n Ending Process")
    listener.deactivate()
    listener. destroy()
```